# strings xml Locale not changing

Tags: android, locale

The problem I am having is when launching the application in another locale for example "de" the program is not using the strings.xml (de) which it is meant to use.

Layout of 'values' directory screenshot

UPDATE: The "en" locale file works and the app successfully uses the strings of this file but when setting to another language the application reverts back to the default strings.xml file. I have even set the files to the exact same and still no luck.

**EDIT:** Fixed this problem by finding the following in my application build gradle!
**resConfigs "en"**

Comment: what if you delete `strings.xml` that dont have any locale?

Comment: then the application doesn't start at all crashes on build as it returns a Resource not found exception

Comment: Please share your string.xml (de version) and original version. Probably you missed some of the string items on de version. Probably number of string attribute missmatched on de from the original version.

Comment: This cannot be the problem as I tested this by pasting the default strings.xml into each file and changing the last letter by something I'd notice, when launching the application again it displayed the strings.xml (default) one again.

Comment: `it returns a Resource not found exception` Then it doesn't find one or more of the required string resources.

Comment: are you setting the locale yourself in the app? or u mean when language is changed device-level?

Comment: no it is going by the locale of the device

Comment: Well, each time you set the locale on your device, you need to restart your Activity/ies.

Comment: Since you have resolved this problem, please put your solution as an Answer to the question so that others in the future might more easily find it.

Comment: I typed resConfig "ko", "xxhdpi" for reducing building time..
OMG This is the answer
Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** Changed the app gradle script. It had initially had resConfigs "en" which was preventing any other locale to work so I removed the line. It is inside the default config.

**Before:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.xxxx.xxxx'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1000
        versionName '1.05'
        resConfigs "en"
    }
}
```

**After:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.xxxx.xxxx'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1000
        versionName '1.05'
    }
}
```

Comment: you Just saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: @PSandeshBaliga no worries, I literally sat there for 2 days trying all different algorithms and it was right infront of me.

Comment: Ya lol. Same happened to me. I was wondering why on earth it wouldn't work with n different ways :(